# Classify whether the limit converges or diverges and if its bounded or unbounded

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

$$\left\{\frac{(-1)^n100^n}{n!}\right\}$$

So, I know $\left\{\frac{100^n}{n!}\right\}$ is a basic null sequence, although here itll oscillate between negative and positive values dependent on the odd/even nature of $n$. However, I think it'll still converge to $0$ and be a null sequence eventually. and its also bounded. Am I wrong?

Comment: try to prove the following statement applying the definition of convergence: if $x_n$ is a null sequence, then $(-1)^{n} x_n$ is also a null sequence.

Comment: Note that a *limit* neither converges nor diverges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Squeeze theorem will do
$$\frac{-100^n}{n!}\leq\frac{(-1)^n100^n}{n!}\leq \frac{100^n}{n!}$$
Both of which converge to zero.

Answer (score 0):

By the formal definition of limit, we say that $a_n \to 0$ if given any $\epsilon >0$ there exist $n_0 \in \Bbb{N} $ such that $|a_n|<\epsilon$ for all $n\geq n_0$. Since we are only concerned about the absolut value, the $(-1)^n $ doesn't really matter in this case. Therefore since $\frac {100^n}{n!} \to 0$ also does $\frac {(-1)^n 100^n}{n!}$

Answer (score 0):

Notice that if $|a_n| \to 0$, then $a_n \to 0$.
Suppose that $a_n \to 0$. Then there exists $N \in \mathbb N$ so that $|a_N|<\epsilon$ for any $\epsilon$.  Then the result is clear. Notice that you need the limit to be zero. For example, $\{(-1)^n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ does not converge, while its absolute value clearly does.

Anyway, apply the first fact to solve your problem.

**edit** every convergent sequence is bounded. Let $\epsilon>0$, and $a_n$ be a sequence that converges to $L$. There are two options:
There exists some $N$ so that $n \geq N$ implies that $|a_n-L|<\epsilon$, and so $a_n<L+\epsilon$.

Otherwise, take $\max\{a_1,\ldots,a_{N-1}\}=M_1$.

Now take $\max\{L+\epsilon, M_1\}$. Clearly this bounds the sequence$(a_n)$

Comment: How do i show bounded or unbounded?

Comment: every  real-valued convergent sequence is bounded.

Comment: @user1023 see my edit